# Error Starting logstash When Using path.config in pipelines.yml

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I have a very simple pipelines.yml file defined with a single pipeline. It looks like this:

```
- pipeline.id: testPipe1
path.config: "/tmp/test.conf"
pipeline.workers: 1
```

when starting logstash I received the following error:

**ERROR: Failed to read pipelines yaml file. Location [path to file].pipelines.yml**

, where "path to file" is valid path to yaml file.

the contents of test.conf are:

```
input { stdin {} } output { stout {codec => rubydebug} }
```

when I comment out path.config line and use:

```
config.string: input { stdin {} } output { stout {codec => rubydebug} }
```

, then logstash creates the pipeline and starts up fine.

What is going on here? Grateful for any insights. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note is pipelines (with .conf extension) are considered **config**. Settings (with .yml) extension are your **settings**. I would separate these into two different directories then run the command line this.

```
./bin/logstash --path.settings /path_to_your_yml_settings_dir --path.config=/path_to_your_conf_pipelines
```

Comment: thanks Samuurai this did it. Appreciate it. Thanks you Furhan S. as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your pipelines.yml file should be placed at "--path.settings" which you would pass on the command line when starting logstash process. Something like:

```
./bin/logstash --path.settings /path_to_your_settings_dir_containing_your_configs_and_pipelines.yml
```

Comment: Thanks Furhan S. However, my issue is with path.config in the pipelines.yml. As I said above, logstash runs fine when I put the pipeline's configuration in line (with config.string).

Comment: Path to config file gets included in pipeline.yml which is looked up in --path.settings

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not understanding what you mean. I do have already the path.settings command line option when I start logstash. I put the path to the config directory. That config directory has the pipelines.yml and  a separate config file for each pipeline. It finds the pipelines.yml file because logstash works fine when I use config.string rather than path.config. Am I being unclear or maybe misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 0):

Passing the path to my `pipelines.yml` in `--path.settings` when starting Logstash did not work out for me.

Removing the quotation marks in `path.config` worked:

```
- pipeline.id: testPipe1
  path.config: /tmp/test.conf
  pipeline.workers: 1
```

Then run `./bin/logstash`